# Matlab Psychophysics Toolbox not responding to keyboard input

Tags: matlab, keyboard-events

I tried **KbWait** in Matlab Psychophysics toolbox (in Windows 7) to receive inputs from the subject. However, I'm using two monitors (one for experiment display and another for running Matlab) and although I can see the characters being typed in the command window, Psychophysics toolbox seems not to receive the input. I didn't have this problem in Mac OS. I wonder if anyone has faced and solve this problem using Windows 7. 
Thanks.